# Laravel Echo not listening to broadcast

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-echo, pusher-js

I have these values in env:

```
    BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
    QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
    PUSHER_APP_ID=some_id
    PUSHER_APP_KEY=some_key
    PUSHER_APP_SECRET=some_secret
    PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=some_cluster
```

This is how I broadcast the event

```
    broadcast(new MessageSent(auth()->user(), $message));
```

MessageSent:

```
    class MessageSent implements ShouldBroadcast {
        use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

        public $user;
        public $message;

        public function __construct(User $user, Message $message) {
            $this->user = $user;
            $this->message = $message;
        }

        public function broadcastOn() {
            return new PrivateChannel('chat');
        }

        public function broadcastAs() {
            return 'MessageSent';
        }
    }
```

**channel**:

```
    Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user) {
        return Auth::check();
    });
```

How I listen to broadcast:

```
    window.Echo.private(`chat`)
       .listen('.MessageSent', (e) => {
           console.log('logged');
    });
```

I looked at the pusher debug console and it fired a connection, authorized, subscribed, and every message I sent it logs correctly.

[image]

I also run `php artisan queue:listen`

Comment: Do you see success if you remove the `.` character from the listen? 

  `.listen('MessageSent', (e) => {`

Comment: I have solved it. Its just the app settings in Pusher I turned it all off